# Compare month and day (not year) in Excel

Tags: excel, date, formulas, calculation

`'Worksheet1'!A2` contains a date.

If the month **and** day of `A2` are between 0 and 7 days *after* **today's** month and day, I want `B2` to equal `A2`. Otherwise, `B2` should equal "".

### Example

[image]

In other words, ignoring the years, if the month and day of `A2`  are within 7 days of today, I want `B2` to display `A2` with the year being the same as the current year. Otherwise, I want `B2` to display nothing.

Answer (score 1):

then just subtract the date as if it is this year and check discrepancy.

```
=IF(OR(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(A2),DAY(A2))-TODAY()={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}),A2,"")
```

[image]

Comment: Great solution, Scott! Dusty, if you want `A2` to have the same year as the current year, use `=IF(OR(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(A2),DAY(A2))-TODAY()={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}),DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(A2),DAY(A2)),"")`. I may have I misinterpreted that part of your question, though.